# How to select fields according to "signs" from other table? (All doctors from CV)

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

**Employee**:

| E_name | CV |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | I am a doctor in a hospital |
| Eva | I am a dentist in a clinic |
| Carl | I am a mechanical engineer |

**Doctor_sign**

| signid | sign_word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | doctor |
| 2 | dentist |
| 3 | ophthalmologist |
| ... | ... |

I want to SELECT all doctors from the Employee table according to the list from Doctor_sign.

I am looking for the following result :
| E_name   | CV                             |
| -------- | ------------------------------ |
| Adam     | I am a doctor in a hospital    |
| Eva      | I am a dentist in a clinic     |

because of (doctor, dentist) word in the CV

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Employee.E_name, Employee.CV, Doctor_sign.sign_word
FROM Employee 
LEFT JOIN Doctor_sign
ON Employee.CV LIKE lower('%' || Doctor_sign.sign_word || '%')
WHERE Doctor_sign.sign_word IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Doctor_sign.sign_word
;
```

Here is answer for SQLite

Comment: Don't you just want an inner join?